# Gap in my headset - should I be concerned?

Tags: headset

I serviced my headset as a part of my maintenance plan. After reassembling it, I noticed this small gap in my headset. Am I missing something or is this normal? I am using a FSA headset, never been replaced.

The gap in question is between the bottom spacer and the upper headset bearing. It is as if the spacers are not thick enough or the bearing is particularly wide(?).

[image: image of my actual headset]

Comment: I’m not seeing the gap you are asking about. Can you indicate where specifically the issue is?

Comment: Between the upper head-tube race and dust cover (or top cover)

Comment: Any problems that stem from it (no pun intended), like headset play or forks not moving freely?

Comment: Looks like it's FSA "The Pig" BMX 1-1/8" threadless headset. On BMX bikes steerer spacers are not used and stem hides the gap.

Comment: Theres no problem with moving the fork nor headset @DoNut

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, the gap looks like normal bearing without external seal. The moving parts must not touch each other so that they can move, machining has tolerances and materials flex, so there must be some gap. Many modern headsets have a rubber gasket inside to protect the bearings. If it is a FSA The Pig as suspected in comments, there should be one.

Anyway, there are external neoprene protectors that go over the headset for additional layer of protection. Usually they are not needed but if you ride in unusually wet and dirty conditions one may be good for your peace of mind.

Comment: +1, thanks for the response!